# Como pré-definir valores em struct array em C

Tags: c, array, struct

Tenho duvidas em como posso atribuir valores a um struct que esteja em array.

A minha ideia era a seguinte:

```
typedef struct venda {
    int refVenda;
    int idCliente;
    int preco;
    int quantidade;
    char categoria[100];    
} VENDA;
//vendas pre-definidas
struct vendas[0] = {13, 10, 50, 2, "Sapatos"};
struct vendas[1] = {14, 11, 150, 1, "Sapatilhas"};
struct vendas[2] = {15, 12, 70, 6, "Calças"};

// na main tenho -> VENDA vendas[MAXVENDAS];
```

mas esta dando errado.

O objetivo do exercício é adicionar vendas(o que já fiz), mas é necessário que já existam algumas vendas pré-definidas no código para depois fazer uma lista.

Código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXVENDAS 10

typedef struct venda {
    int refVenda;
    int idCliente;
    int preco;
    int quantidade;
    char categoria[100];    
} VENDA;

//vendas pre-defenidas
struct vendas[0] = {13, 10, 50, 2, "Sapatos"};
struct vendas[1] = {14, 11, 150, 1, "Sapatilhas"};
struct vendas[2] = {15, 12, 70, 6, "Calças"};

VENDA novaVenda(){
    VENDA vendaTemp;
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("\nIntroduza a referencia de venda: ");
    scanf("%i", &vendaTemp.refVenda); //depois fazer sistema para defenir referencia automaticamente
    printf("\nIntroduza a identificação de cliente: ");
    scanf("%i", &vendaTemp.idCliente);
    printf("\nIntroduza o preço: ");
    scanf("%i", &vendaTemp.preco);
    printf("\nIntroduza a quantidade: ");
    scanf("%i", &vendaTemp.quantidade);
    
    int a = 0; //enquanto a = 0 roda o comando dnv
    while(a == 0){
        printf("\n1 - Camisolas | 2 - Calças | 3 - Sapatilhas | 4 - Acessórios\nIntroduza a categoria: ");
        int opcao;
        scanf("%i", &opcao);
        switch(opcao){
            case 1:
            strcpy(vendaTemp.categoria, "Camisolas"); a = 1; break;
            case 2: 
            strcpy(vendaTemp.categoria, "Calças"); a = 1; break;
            case 3: 
            strcpy(vendaTemp.categoria, "Sapatilhas"); a = 1; break;
            case 4: 
            strcpy(vendaTemp.categoria, "Acessórios"); a = 1; break;
            default: printf("\nOpção Invalida!\n"); break;
        }
    }
}

void listarVendas(VENDA vendas[], int qntVendas){
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < qntVendas; i++){
        printf("\nVenda %i - Referência da venda: %i | Identificador do Cliente: %i | Preço: %i€ | Quantidade: %i | Categoria do produto: %s\n", 
        i++, vendas[i].refVenda, vendas[i].idCliente, vendas[i].preco, vendas[i].quantidade, vendas[i].categoria);
    }
}

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    
    VENDA vendas[MAXVENDAS];
    int qntVendas = 0;
    
    while(1){
        printf("\n1 - Introduzir venda");
        printf("\n2 - Listar todas as vendas");
        printf("\n3 - Listar todas as vendas de uma categoria especifica");
        printf("\n4 - Modificar preço/quantidade de uma venda");
        printf("\nIntroduza a opção! - ");
        int opcao;
        scanf(" %i", &opcao);

        switch(opcao){
            case 1: 
                vendas[qntVendas] = novaVenda();
                qntVendas ++;
                break;
            case 2:
                listarVendas(vendas, qntVendas); break;
        }
    } 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seu programa não está bom e acho que vai ter trabalho além do necessário paa concluir assim.

De todo modo, eis um exemplo de como declarar isso em `C`:

```
    VENDA vendas[MAXVENDAS] =
    {
        [0] =
        {
            .refVenda = 13,
            .idCliente = 10,
            .preco = 50,
            .quantidade = 2,
            .categoria = "Sapatos"
        },
        [1] =
        {
            .refVenda = 14,
            .idCliente = 11,
            .preco = 150,
            .quantidade = 1,
            .categoria = "Sapatilhas"
        },
        [2] =
        {
            .refVenda = 15,
            .idCliente = 12,
            .preco = 70,
            .quantidade = 6,
            .categoria = "Calças"
        }
    };
```

É simples assim. Você pode escrever direto e inicializar qualquer posição do vetor. Não precisa nem estar em ordem.

### um programa completo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXVENDAS 10

typedef struct
{
    int refVenda;
    int idCliente;
    int preco;
    int quantidade;
    char categoria[100];
} VENDA;

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR");
    VENDA vendas[MAXVENDAS] =
    {
        [0] =
        {
            .refVenda = 13,
            .idCliente = 10,
            .preco = 50,
            .quantidade = 2,
            .categoria = "Sapatos"
        },
        [1] =
        {
            .refVenda = 14,
            .idCliente = 11,
            .preco = 150,
            .quantidade = 1,
            .categoria = "Sapatilhas"
        },
        [2] =
        {
            .refVenda = 15,
            .idCliente = 12,
            .preco = 70,
            .quantidade = 6,
            .categoria = "Calças"
        }
    };

    /*
    struct vendas[0] = { 13, 10, 50, 2, "Sapatos" };
    struct vendas[1] = { 14, 11, 150, 1, "Sapatilhas" };
    struct vendas[2] = { 15, 12, 70, 6, "Calças" };
     */
    printf("3 primeiras categorias: \"%s\", \"%s\" e \"%s\"\n",
        vendas[0].categoria,
        vendas[1].categoria,
        vendas[2].categoria);
    return 0;
}
```

#### saída do exemplo

```
3 primeiras categorias: "Sapatos", "Sapatilhas" e "Calças"
```

#### [quase off-topic]

Algumas coisas que poderia mudar:

- sua estrutura pode e deve ser anônima. Pra que 2 nomes?
- `fflush()` só está definida para entrada
- TESTE o retorno de `scanf()`. Leia o manual
- não escreva um programa interativo a toa
- não retorne por valor e sim por referência